# Spring Boot Admin illegal character while health check

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I have deployed few Spring boot applications using spring cloud Netflix OSS and configured Spring boot Admin to monitor those application connecting to Eureka server. But for two of the applications, I am getting below error. Could you please let me know what could be the cause of this error and how to mitigate this.

This endpoint health URL is provided by Spring boot actuator and output of the heath URL is `{"description":"Spring Cloud Eureka Discovery Client","status":"UP"}`

Error in the log

```
2017-10-02 18:29:31.790 ERROR 5976 --- [DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0] d.c.b.a.d.ApplicationDiscoveryListener   : Couldn't register application for service org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClient$EurekaServiceInstance@3e988b86

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 61: http://xxxx:56412/manage/health 
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.discovery.EurekaServiceInstanceConverter.getHealthUrl(EurekaServiceInstanceConverter.java:46) ~[spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.0.jar!/:1.5.0]
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.discovery.DefaultServiceInstanceConverter.convert(DefaultServiceInstanceConverter.java:64) ~[spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.0.jar!/:1.5.0]
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.discovery.ApplicationDiscoveryListener.register(ApplicationDiscoveryListener.java:138) [spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.0.jar!/:1.5.0]
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.discovery.ApplicationDiscoveryListener.discover(ApplicationDiscoveryListener.java:94) [spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.0.jar!/:1.5.0]
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.discovery.ApplicationDiscoveryListener.discoverIfNeeded(ApplicationDiscoveryListener.java:85) [spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.0.jar!/:1.5.0]
    at de.codecentric.boot.admin.discovery.ApplicationDiscoveryListener.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationDiscoveryListener.java:80) [spring-boot-admin-server-1.5.0.jar!/:1.5.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:253) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:174) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:137) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) [spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.onCacheRefreshed(CloudEurekaClient.java:98) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:943) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1451) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1418) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar!/:1.6.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 61: http://xxxxx:56412/manage/health 
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: looks like the health path has a trailing white space...

Comment: But This is actuator generated. How to mitigate that?

Answer (score 1):

There was an extra space at the end of the URL

```
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrlPath=${management.context-path}/health
```

It should be

```
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrlPath=${management.context-path}/health
```